# A Traveling Salesman Variant

Tags: graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

Is their a variant of Traveling Salesman Problem or other algorithms about the following problem:

Say G is an incomplete undirected weighted graph. V is a subset of vertices of G.

How to find a simple closed circuit along V (and probably some other vertices of G), which has a minimal weight between each two vertices of V.

Thank you

---------------------- edit ------------------------

Is there a name or published document or related research paper for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, because V (which is a subset of vertices of G as you state) is itself a weighted graph - calculate the edges of V first so you can ignore G.

For example this input of G:

```
G1 (Va) -- 5 meter --> G2 (no V) -- 10 meter --> G3 (Vb)
```

Can be simplified to this input of V:

```
Va -- 15 meter --> Vb
```

The fun starts when you have the input has multiple paths between to V vertices (with no other V vertices in between):

```
G1 (Va) -- 5 meter --> G2 (no V) -- 10 meter --> G3 (Vb)
G1 (Va) -- 7 meter --> G4 (no V) -- 7 meter --> G3 (Vb)
```

Then the simplified form is (it takes the second route):

```
Va -- 14 meter --> Vb
```

Use the Dijkstra algorithm during that simplification.

Second, apply a good TSP algorithm on V. It's NP-complete so there is no perfect algorithm. There are many available frameworks depending on your programming language ([java](http://www.optaplanner.org/), [C/C++](http://www.adaptivebox.net/CILib/code/tspcodes_link.html), ...).

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty awesome! One follow up question: is there any related research paper or any other published document about this problem?

Comment: Or is there a name for this sort of problems?

Comment: TSP is one of the most intensively studied research problems. There are plenty of papers and books about it (see Google Scolar). I doubt you 'll find one specifically of your form however, because - from a research perspective - the complexity it adds can be simplified away without any trade-off in the TSP.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and I really want to know is there a name for this particular Dijkstra algorithm + TSP problem, so that I can know the efficiency and compare different solutions?